# Numero par o impar y devuelve bool true o false

Tags: c++, booleano

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que se me pide hacer una función de tipo booleano que reciba un entero y devuelva `true` si es par o `false` si es impar, pero no sé muy bien cómo utilizar la parte de `bool`.

Esta es la parte del código que llevo hasta ahora:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numero;

    cout << "Digite el numero a analizar: \n";
    cin >> numero;

}

bool numero(int numero) {

    if (numero % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "El numero es Par";
    }
    else {
        cout << "El numero es Impar";
    }
    return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: // Retorna true si el argumento "num" es menor que noventa. // De lo contrario, retorna false. // Tu código: necesito ayuda con este ejercicio por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si indentamos correctamente la función...

```
bool numero(int numero)
{
    if(numero % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout<<"El numero es Par";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"El numero es Impar";
    }

    return true;
    return false;
}
```

Vemos que has puesto los dos `return` seguidos. Como la ejecución de un `return` implica que el programa abandona la función, el segundo `return` **nunca** se ejecutará y la función devolverá siempre `true`.

La solución es trivial, basta con mover cada `return` dentro de la parte del condicional que le corresponda:

```
bool numero(int numero)
{
    if (numero % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "El numero es Par";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "El numero es Impar";
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Como has visto, la indentación del código es importante para leer fácilmente el código. Si esto ya pasa en una función de 7 líneas, imagínate en un proyecto de varias decenas de miles de líneas de código.

Comment: Bueno, yo antes aclararia que llama a una funcion como una variable, y que el CIN lo hace a la variable no a la funcion

Comment: @Max `cout` no pide datos sino que los muestra por pantalla ... quítalos si no quieres que salgan los mensajes ... tu decides

Comment: ya veo, eso tecnicamente es independiente, pero ahora, modificando mi codigo, me da el error error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token|error: expected '}' at end of input| me podrias explicar eso porfavor ?

Comment: Esa sería una pregunta diferente a la original, no crees? Esto no es un hilo de un foro que deba crecer indefinidamente ... tu haces una pregunta y recibes respuestas que te ayuden ... si tienes varias preguntas puedes formular varias preguntas que nadie te va a decir nada

Comment: _Si tabulamos correctamente la función..._ La función no está tabulada. Ni correctamente indentada para los estándares del sitio, que piden que se indente con 4 espacios, no con 2. Dejando eso a un lado, la respuesta está bien.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez el estilo del código es irrelevante mientras sea consistente

Comment: @braver sin acritud, no puedo estar más en desacuerdo. Por supuesto, lo más importante es que el código funcione, que la respuesta esté bien. Pero no hay que descuidar el formato. Y menos cuando el sitio te pide seguir unas convenciones concretas de formato.